# Foreman Parameters accents not allowed

Tags: puppet, foreman

I'm using foreman to manage my servers launching "Run puppet" from theforeman interface. My classes use some values defined as foreman "parameters" to work.

Everything works fine, but not when a parameter has a special character (for example: Español). This is a bug?

Example:

1.- I just add a new parameter as follows:

```
languages = Español, English
```

2.- And I go to the server and execute:

```
puppet agent -t
notice: Ignoring --listen on onetime run
info: Retrieving plugin
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find node     'node1.domain.com'; cannot compile
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Comment: Have you tried with an N without the tilde? Or alternatively with `%F1` instead of `ñ`, i.e.: `Espa%F1ol`?

Comment: You enter those into a foreman web form? Have you tried fiddling with the browser's page encoding setting?

Comment: Ok, now the "puppet agent -t" is working with the variable "languages = Espa%F1ol". But the problem is that my template doesn't take the proper value:

**template.erb**
This is my language: <%= @languages %>

**result**
This is my language: Espa%F1ol

**result expected**
This is my language: Español

Comment: @SebastianSuarez I opened a bug ticket for that, it's still a problem in Foreman 1.7.2 (latest stable) and in the development branch: http://projects.theforeman.org/issues/9541 Thanks!